# C++ Using the "this" pointer as a normal pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I am currently trying to use the "this" pointer to pass a pointer to a function:

```
void GameObject::process_events()
{
    std::vector<ObjectEvent*>::iterator it;
    for (it = events.begin(); it != events.end(); it++)
        (*it)->process(this);
}

Class ObjectEvent
{
private:
    bool* trigger;
    void (*response)(GameObject*);
public:
    process(GameObject* obj)
    {
        if (*trigger)
            response(obj);
    }
};
```

But I get an error:

```
No matching function call to 'ObjectEvent::process(GameObject* const)'
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: yes, `this` is a normal pointer.  however, the functions you've listed would not give that error.  Please create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Alright, I'll put in my real code, one second

Comment: If that's the real code, it looks good. Sure there wasn't a const in there somewhere? Just for future readers' sake.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me.  Copyable objects that are const can generally be copied (unless someone screwed up the copy constructor, which is not the case here).  `GameObject*` should be initializable from `this`, which is of type `GameObject* const`, unless attempted from a const member, which is not the case.  Your code should, in fact, work.  That you say it is not means the compiler you're using is trash...or you are confused.  The latter is more likely.

Comment: That is not your real code nor an SSCCE.  `Class` is a dead givaway, as is the fact you have functions with no return type. [Somehow, I feel like you failed to understand the importance of an SSCCE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9d901bedcd3391d277ffb911f47280bf-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: I did fix the problem, you were right, it was a problem that I neglected to post. In my header file I had the function defined as a GameObject* const for some reason. I was trying to debug the .cpp file. Thanks for the link, I'll try and write better code for my questions next time.

Comment: I suggest putting the const back in the code to make the question readable. Perhaps with a little edit message at the top, explaining the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Judging by your error message, process_events() appears to actually be a const function.

```
void GameObject::process_events() const
{
    process(this);
}
```

If so, then `this` is a const pointer and process() must take a `const GameObject *`. Otherwise process() could modify the point that gets passed to it, which violates process_events's promise not to modify `this`.

```
void process(const GameObject* obj);
```

Alternatively, remove the const modifier from process_events().

Comment: Yep, you were right, my header file was wrong and I kept trying to fix the .cpp file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the member function you're returning `this` from or using `this` in is **const**, then it will be a **const** pointer. If the member function is not declared **const**, the pointer won't be either.

```
void GameObject::process_events()
{
    // ...
    process(this); // 'this' is NOT a const pointer
}

void GameObject::process_events() const
{
    // ...
    process(this); // 'this' IS a const pointer
}
```